# php-loader webpack 2 - php to html

Tags: javascript, php, webpack, webpack-2

I am trying to convert a php page build with a couple of php includes in it to html page.. and i am not sure if [php-loader](https://github.com/redcatjs/webpack-php-loader) is the correct plugin, i followed the instruction however i am getting a error

```
var fileContent = require("php!./file.php");
```

i have placed `var fileContent = require("php!./file.php");` inside my `index.js` and also tried it on `webpack.config.js` version and still i can't run it right..

Does anyone have able to make the php-loader work and what are the exact steps for it? since the instructions in [webpack-php-loader](https://github.com/redcatjs/webpack-php-loader) is not really specific.

Thanks in advance "life saver"